# Python - converting set into list

Tags: python, list, set

in the line of code below, I'm trying to process `track_ids`, a `set` which does not allow `indexing`.

```
track_name = sp.track(track_ids[i])['name']
```

how do I convert `track_ids` into a `list` so I'm able to index it?

EDIT: this is the complete function:

```
def filterBelowThreshold(product, filter_name, track_ids, values, 
    xsongs, threshold):
    print product.upper(), 'PLAYLIST:'
    for i, x in enumerate(values):
        if x < threshold:
            track_name = sp.track(track_ids[i])['name']
            #append minding foreign track names
            xsongs.add(track_name.encode("utf-8"))
            print product.upper(),'-', "{} = {}".format(track_name.encode("utf-8"), x), filter_name
```

Comment: You can just go over it with a for loop can't you? And also, you could trying passing the set to `list()`.

Comment: Being it an not-indexable (without ordering) set, you have no way to guarantee that your index `i` in `values` actually refers to a specific `track_id`

Comment: What follows is the question, in what way the track_ids and the values are related and if so, wether you would preferably join them before calling the function to assure your order gets not messed up. (Or if you would want to apply a filter on the list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can convert a `set` into a `list` by calling the function `list(track_ids)`.

Please notice that the elements in this new list will not have a meaningful ordering, so accessing it like you are doing with an `i` index that enumerates over another list is not correct, assuming that you think that the elements in `values` and `track_ids` are somewhat related.

But, if you really want to get `values` and `track_ids` paired (likely being random pairings) you might try this more concise way:

```
for val, track_id in zip(values,list(track_ids)):
```

Comment: order is not a necessity here, as long as I end up with a list of `songs`(track_names) an another list with their corresponding `track_ids`

Comment: list to set does not preserve ordering. Is that true for set to list as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would say like that:

```
[x for x in track_ids][index]
```

Comment: The OP has posted a complete function. Perhaps you should apply your suggestion to the full version of their code?

Comment: But sets are unordered, thus the list will also be unordered - indexing into it makes no sense.

Comment: moreover, you can convert a `set` into a `list` by calling the function `list(track_ids)`

Comment: @fstab this worked. care to answer?

Comment: @data_garden: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you could post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

No need to go for loop, just wrap your `set` with `list` function call, see an example below

```
#Index Doesn't work with set
>>> set([1,2,3])[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

#convert set to list like this and indexing would work.
>>> list(set([1,2,3]))[1]
=> 2
```